# How to declare a script to run on specific user during ssh login

Tags: 16.04

I was able to run a script in bashrc when any user access the server via ssh. However, I would like to run this script to specific user only.

Here is my command in bashrc.
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
    /home/ubuntu/xxx.sh
fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `.bashrc` file in user's home directory and it will be executed only for that user. In that way, you can achieve that it is executed for specific user. However, the user might delete `.bashrc` file. You can probably make it to be owned by root. Another solution is to put additional condition in global `bashrc` like that:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ] && [ $USER == "ubuntu" ]]; then
    /home/ubuntu/xxx.sh
fi
```

In that way, user does not have permission to change global bashrc file unless she has enough privileges.

Comment: Thanks nobody..I will try your recommendation.

Comment: I got some error upon trying your solution. However, I manage it using the new syntax below:

if [ -n $SSH_CONNECTION  &&  $USER == "ubuntu" ]; then
    /home/ubuntu/xxx.sh
fi